# remote control nginx configuration

Tags: git, nginx, configuration, docker

I want to avoid connecting to remote machine to edit nginx conf files.
I'd rather control it from git and jenkins.

What's the best practice to manage my nginx configuration history in a way that I can easily test it, and role back?

- (can git+docker+nginx be a solution?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a volume with comfiguration and mount it to nginx container. When you need to update your configuration, just replace files in volume (git, copy files from host, etc) and send reload command to nginx service via docer exec.
Also, you can mount (read only) host directory with nginx config to container.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/

Answer (score 0):

I like the accepted answer @komex and it is fine but requires you to maintain a volume and does not address test lifecycles and deployment as asked in the question. Also building volumes with files should be done after we ensure the files are correct and tested successfully.

Here my evolved recipe:-

**Versioning**

Must use some SCM such as git. Keep your configurations in a git repository.

**Testing**

Use CI/CD Jenkins and use docker to build image from nginx with the configuration files. You might want to use environment variable instead of hardcoding any URLs on your configuration so that in your test setup you could point to dummy values and run your unit tests. Your unit test could be just a bunch of curls and expected responses. After tests you can destroy this setup easily.

You CI ensures correct configuration everything the job runs.

**Deployment**

Now you may build volumes for deployment. Attach/Detach your volume.
But you are in a full k8s environment I would just build my image from ngnix (just like the Test job above in the CI) and deploy the pod and not even bother volumes or reloading.